# Can't correctly delete xml elements via listview

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Hello I would like to understand why my listview delete (patcherButton4) is not working. I just wan't that when the user as selected a item in the list and then he click on delete button, the xml record get deleted. :\

```
        private void patcherButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument munchercrawler = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Entretelp\InfoList.xml");

            listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();

            munchercrawler.Root.Elements("Name").
                FirstOrDefault(item => item.Element("Name").Value == listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text)
                    .Remove();

            munchercrawler.Save(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Entretelp\InfoList.xml");

            listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: So much code and text for what appears to be a simple problem. Please narrow down the issue.

Comment: I would like to understand why my listview delete (patcherButton4) and edit (patcherButton1) are not working. I basically want to know why when I execute my delete code which is patcherbutton4, it does nothing. Just check the first code box its where everything is...

Comment: That's your job. Use your debugger, step through some code. Pasting a wall of text and code and basically saying "doesnt work, pls fix" is not a great way to get your question answered. Like I said, you need to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I narrowed the most important problem. Also I pasted all the code and made a lot of explanation cause I did not knew what you needed to understand my probleme and I don't even know how to use the debugger. :/ As I said I am really new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because you try to get `listView1.SelectedItems[0]` after calling `listView1.SelectedItems.Clear()` which makes `listView1.SelectedItems` empty?

Comment: Yhea but the problem is that listView1.SelectedItems.Clear() is supposed to delete the Selected item only on the listView1 and if I restart the form or the application, the deleted item is going to be loaded again. So its just to clear it from the form. But anyway, its not working, its not deleting the record in the xml file or on the listView1. So its like null code, must be using the wrong syntax or something :\

Comment: @user2929556 Nope, `listView1.SelectedItems.Clear()` is not supposed to delete anything. It just *clears* the selected item collection, i.e., to make you selecting nothing in the list view. You need to call `Remove()` on `listView1.Items` to remove an item from the list view.

Comment: Oh and btw I did not knew what is was supposed to do or not to do. I was just thinking that it was deleting the items. Also... thanks for the precise and helpful help! -_-

Comment: Nop, I am asking some friends who know how it work but you did not explained to me how I could remove it from the xml file...